# How to retrieve image from database(image stored is in binary form)

Tags: c#, asp.net

**this is the place where i want to display the images**

```
`<asp:Repeater ID="rptr" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Image ID="img1" style="height:120px; width:120px" runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

`
**this is the code i have used to retrieve images**

```
string query = "select Image from tblImage where UserName='" + uname + "'";
               DataSet ds = new DataSet();
              SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, scon);
              da.Fill(ds);
              rptr.DataSource = ds;
              rptr.DataBind();
```

*now i want to set imageurl for the image control present within repeater control but the problem is that my image is present in binary form so i cant set the imageurl as Image`ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Image") %>'`("Image" is Column Name of the table where Image is stored in binary form). How can i convert the image into string format and set that into ImageUrl*

Answer (score 0):

HTML img element like so:

```
<asp:Image ID="image" style="height:120px; width:120px" runat="server"/>
```

And in code behind do this:

```
image.src = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
```

Where imageBytes is a byte[] which you retrieve from database.

You are done. The image will be displayed.

Comment: but ,since, the image control is present within repeater control i cant get the imageId of the imge control

Comment: try this-
 foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptr.Items)
    {
        Image image = (Image)item.FindControl("img1");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(image.ImageUrl);
    }

Comment: will it show all the images present in the database or only one??